# CakePHP2.6.0でチェックボックスをCSV保存したい。

Tags: php, cakephp

データベースに以下の3つのテーブルを作る。

```
create table users(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    comment_id varchar(50),
    created datetime not null,
    modified datetime not null);

create table comments(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(50));

create table groups(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(50));
```

## cake bake all

```
app/Console/cake bake model all
app/Console/cake bake controller all
app/Console/cake bake view all
```

## app/Controller/UsersController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Paginator');

    public function index() {
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }

    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('user', $this->User->find('first', $options));
    }

    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();

            //Edit from here
            if ($this->request->data['User']['comment_id']['group_id'] !== '') {
                $csv = implode(',', $this->request->data['User']['comment_id']['group_id']);
                $this->request->data['User']['comment_id']['group_id'] = $csv;
            } else {
                $this->request->data['User']['comment_id']['group_id'] = '';
            }

            //Edit far
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $comments = $this->User->Comment->find('list');
        $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('comments', 'groups'));
    }

    public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {

            //Edit from here
            if ($this->request->data['User']['comment_id']['group_id'] !== '') {
                $csv = implode(',', $this->request->data['User']['comment_id']['group_id']));
                $this->request->data['User']['comment_id']['group_id'] = $csv;
            }

            //Edit far
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->User->find('first', $options);
        }
        $comments = $this->User->Comment->find('list');
        $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('comments', 'groups'));
    }

    public function delete($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
        if ($this->User->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

## app/View/Users/add.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add User'); ?></legend>
    <?php
      echo $this->Form->input('name');
      echo $this->Form->input('comment_id',
                              array(
                                  'type' => 'select',
                                  'options' => $comments,
                                  'multiple' => 'checkbox'
                              ));
      echo $this->Form->input('group_id',
                              array(
                                  'type' => 'select',
                                  'options' => $groups,
                                  'multiple' => 'checkbox'
                              ));
    ?>
  </fieldset>
  <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
  <ul>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Comments'), array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Comment'), array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Groups'), array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Group'), array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## app/View/Users/edit.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
  <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Edit User'); ?></legend>
    <?php
      echo $this->Form->input('id');
      echo $this->Form->input('name');
      echo $this->Form->input('comment_id',
                              array(
                                  'type' => 'select',
                                  'options' => $comments,
                                  'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                                  'value' => explode(',', $this->data['User']['comment_id'])
                              ));
      echo $this->Form->input('group_id',
                              array(
                                  'type' => 'select',
                                  'options' => $groups,
                                  'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                                  'value' => explode(',', $this->data['User']['group_id'])
                              ));
    ?>
  </fieldset>
  <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
  <ul>
    <li><?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $this->Form->value('User.id')), array(), __('Are you sure you want to delete', $this->Form->value('User.id'))); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), array('action' => 'index')); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Comments'), array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Comment'), array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Groups'), array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Group'), array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

データベースに保存時グループIDがArrayになりCSVで保存できません。

```
$values = array(
    (int) 0 => 'testuser01',
    (int) 1 => '1,2,3,4',
    (int) 2 => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '2',
        (int) 2 => '3'
    ),
    (int) 3 => '2015-01-11 04:41:20',
    (int) 4 => '2015-01-11 04:41:20'
)
$id = null
$count = (int) 5
$i = (int) 5
$valueInsert = array(
    (int) 0 => ''testuser01'',
    (int) 1 => ''1,2,3,4'',
    (int) 2 => array(
        (int) 0 => ''1'',
        (int) 1 => ''2'',
        (int) 2 => ''3''
    ),
    (int) 3 => ''2015-01-11 04:41:20'',
    (int) 4 => ''2015-01-11 04:41:20''
)
$fieldInsert = array(
    (int) 0 => '`name`',
    (int) 1 => '`comment_id`',
    (int) 2 => '`group_id`',
    (int) 3 => '`modified`',
    (int) 4 => '`created`'
)
```

以下のようにグループIDもCSVで保存できないのでしょうか。

```
$values = array(
    (int) 0 => 'testuser01',
    (int) 1 => '1,2,3,4',
    (int) 2 => '1,2,3,',
    (int) 3 => '2015-01-11 04:41:20',
    (int) 4 => '2015-01-11 04:41:20'
)
$id = null
$count = (int) 5
$i = (int) 5
$valueInsert = array(
    (int) 0 => ''testuser01'',
    (int) 1 => ''1,2,3,4'',
    (int) 2 => ''1,2,3,'',
    (int) 3 => ''2015-01-11 04:41:20'',
    (int) 4 => ''2015-01-11 04:41:20''
)
$fieldInsert = array(
    (int) 0 => '`name`',
    (int) 1 => '`comment_id`',
    (int) 2 => '`group_id`',
    (int) 3 => '`modified`',
    (int) 4 => '`created`'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

まず、users テーブルの定義が、

```
create table users(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(50),
  comment_id varchar(50),
  created datetime not null,
  modified datetime not null
);
```

となっていますが、おそらく group_id が抜けていますよね？

```
group_id varchar(50),
```

次に、`add()` function 内で implode を実行している部分ですが、`app/View/Users/add.ctp` を見る限り、以下の様になるのではないでしょうか？

```
public function add() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->User->create();

    // comment_id
    $this->request->data['User']['comment_id']
        = implode(',', $this->request->data['User']['comment_id']);
    // group_id
    $this->request->data['User']['group_id']
        = implode(',', $this->request->data['User']['group_id']);

    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                     :
```

ただ、現状で、

```
$values = array(
    (int) 0 => 'testuser01',
    (int) 1 => '1,2,3,4',
    (int) 2 => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '2',
        (int) 2 => '3'
    ),
    (int) 3 => '2015-01-11 04:41:20',
    (int) 4 => '2015-01-11 04:41:20'
)
```

となっていますので、前述の変更で期待通りの結果になるのかは分かりません。

Answer (score 0):

本当に、本当にありがとうございました。

質問時に記述した部分で、テーブル作成時「group_id」が確かに抜けていました。

1か月近く、分からなくて、困っていましたので、本当に助かります。
CakePHPもPHPも初心者なもので、こんな事で、いつまでも止まっていました。

このスタック・オーバーフローって凄いところですね。
今後もこのサイトを利用させて頂きたいと思います。

ありがとうございました。

Comment: お礼は回答に書くとあとで見る人が困るかもしれません。実際の内容が書かれたheliacさんの回答にチェックマークを付けて解決にマークするのが一番よいですよ。